# NameError: name 'lname' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone please tell me why I am getting this error even though 'lname' is defined. Error message is in the end.

In k = ['Antony', 'Mark', 'Mdel']. First Name is "Anthony" and Last Name is "Mark Mdel". I know last name Start with the item which starts with "Mar" which is "Mark" here. So need to find the item which starts with "Mar" and extract that item and all items after that. But I am getting the error.

```
k = ['Antony', 'Mark', 'Mdel']

for word in k:
    if word.startswith('Mar'):
        fidx = k.index(word)
        lname_i = k[fidx:]
        lname = []
        for nm in lname_i:
            lname.append(nm)
        print(lname)

    fname = [x for x in k if x not in lname]
    email = fname[0] + '.' + lname[0] + '@' + 'gmail.com'

    fn = ' '.join(fname)
    print(fn)

    ln = ' '.join(lname)
    print(ln)

C:\Users\Path\python.exe C:/Users/Path/Trail.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Path/Trail.py", line 26, in <module>
    fname = [x for x in k if x not in lname]
  File "C:/Users/Path/Trail.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    fname = [x for x in k if x not in lname]
NameError: name 'lname' is not defined
```

Comment: Because `lname` is not in the scope, check your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

`lname` is being defined within the if-statement. However, since 'Antony' doesn't start with 'Mar', the code within the if-statement isn't executed. Thus, `lname` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you. Here I am trying to find the Word starting with 'Mar' and trying to extract items from that word to the end. Please tell me how can I modify it? In brief here I need to Extract 'Mark' 'MDel'

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I can't follow this question. Do you mean that you just want to do the if-statement before your loop? What do you mean you nede to Extract MDel?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.

In k = ['Antony', 'Mark', 'Mdel']. First Name is "Anthony" and Last Name is "Mark Mdel". I know last name Start with the item which starts with "Mar" which is "Mark" here. So need to find the item which starts with "Mar" and extract that item and all items after that. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Yes, in that case, as suggested, run the if-statement (with a list-comprehension) before the for-loop to drop all the items before 'Mark'.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried.

`k = ['Antony', 'Mark', 'Mdel']`

`drop = [x for x in k if not x.startswith('Mar')]`
`print(drop)`

If I use *not* output is ['Antony', 'Mdel']
If I remove *not* output is ['Mark']

How do I remove only 'Antony'? Please guide.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I see I am comparing "Mar" with "MAR" in my code. I have got the alternate solution. Now I am able to get the required Output.